# Stripping RFH2 headers before publishing to Topic for Topic -> Queue subscription

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using a JMS template to publish a message to a topic. The message is being routed from the topic to a queue using a `SUB()` defined on the topic.

I want the RFH2 headers not to be received by the consumer from the destination queue. For the same, I have set the `PSPROP(NONE)` on the topic definition. But still, the RFH2 headers are being received by the consumer from the queue.

Is there some way where I can remove only the RFH2 headers, but still publish the other text or int properties along with the message from the JMS Producer?

Comment: Any feedback Saksham?

Answer (score 1):

What does the receiving application have set for the MQGMO options?

If they set the options to MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE, then MQ will return the message payload only and the message properties (aka named properties) are accessed via the get***Properties() methods.

i.e.

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_PROPERTIES_IN_HANDLE + CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT;
MQMessage receiveMsg = new MQMessage();
queue.get(receiveMsg, gmo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`PSPROP(NONE)` is not an attribute of a `TOPIC` object.

As a MQ admin you can set the `PSPROP(NONE)` on the `SUB` or on the `QUEUE` that is the `DEST` of the `SUB` to prevent the `RFH2` header from being presented to the getting application.